# Showing different derivation trees for same string X

Tags: automata

So I understand how to do this with there being multiple symbols in each possible production, but when it is singular, it seems to get more complicated, or I am overthinking it? Would the left-most derivations be the exact same as the two different derivation trees for some string x in this case? Both cases lead me to S -> T -> ba and S -> V -> ba

I'm also not too sure on the second question, but I think that would be more straight forward with a) answered.

I was hoping someone could help me to understand this a bit better. Here is the grammar, thanks!

For the following grammar
S → T│V 
T → bTa│ba 
V → baV│Λ

a. Show that it is ambiguous (by providing two different derivation trees for some string x, and two different left-most derivations for the same x)

b. Find an equivalent unambiguous grammar.

Comment: Left-most derivations are in bijection with derivation trees.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/64356/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/63448/755